# Регулярное выражение для первого родительского элемента

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой кусок `html` кода который взят из базы.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <p class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> About Us </p>
    <span class="menu0_bottom"></span>
    <div class="menu0_about">Item</div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu_hor">
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li class="no_child_li">
            <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mobile_menu_top hidden-lg hidden-md">
        <div class="button_back_menu">Back<div class="btn_home_img"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile_menu_opening"></div>
</li>

<li class="dropdown menu_new_list col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a target="_top" class="top editablemenuitem" href="link">Item</a>
    <a target="_top" class="menu_new_block" href="link">
        <ul class="menu_new_item">
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </a>        
</li>
```

Есть ли способ с одной регуляркой взять первый `li` с классом `dropdown`?

Объясню суть. Я должен перезаписать в базу. Но с изменением вот той первой части для которой хочу регулярку получить.

Comment: Domdocunent + Xpath

Comment: @RazGalstyan [так](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0bef167adae3202f80e33290617a65005319740) ?

Comment: @splash58 Да это я знаю, но так не так уж легко

Comment: @Эдуард Нет конечно, так половину контента ты взял у главного `li` с классом `dropdown`.

Comment: @RazGalstyan ну у вас вроде бы так и написано: _Есть ли способ с одной регуляркой взять **первый li с классом dropdown** ... первый родительский элемент_

Comment: @Эдуард Да а вы посмотрите первый главный `<li class="dropdown">`. где он заканчивается ? и сколько берет ваша регулярка?

Comment: Рекурсивную регулярку нужно делать.

Comment: А может и без рекурсии  - `'~<li\s[^>]*\bclass="[^"]*\bdropdown(?:(?!<li\s[^>]*\bclass="[^"]*\bdropdown).)*</li>~s'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Результат пустой.

Comment: [Непустой](https://regex101.com/r/D9SaTp/1/). В комметариях на этом сайте вставляются невидимые символы, удалите их.

Comment: @RazGalstyan [Результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e392ec24fd767f5be0536416c983f1636c019116) всё там ок (из камента выше)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо, все заработало.

Comment: со вложенными dropdown работать не будет

Comment: @teran Так и не нужно, всегда так как показано в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование HTML парсера только на первый взгляд выглядит сложным

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
// Ищем в документе все li с классом dropdown и берем первый
$li = $xpath->query('(//li[@class="dropdown"])[1]')->item(0);
$li->parentNode->removeChild($li);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/933620)

Comment: Мне как раз нужно этот `li` удалить и оставить то что под ним.

Comment: Это еще одну строку добавит - обновил

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: Я подумал, вам возможно еще понадобится кое-что, вот тут гляньте - https://eval.in/933627