# Вывести все только определенный блок

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть большой html файл.
Его вывожу на страницу кодом

```
$file = file_get_contents('./file.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

В итоге выводиться весь код HTML файла. Но мне не нужен весь код, мне нужен только такой блок из этого кода:

```html
<TBODY class="content">
   <TR CLASS="offline" id="" nopoll="">
      <TD>тут контент</TD>
    </TR>
    
    <TR CLASS="online" id="" nopoll="">
      <TD>тут контент</TD>
    </TR>
    
    <TR CLASS="connect" id="" nopoll="">
      <TD>тут контент</TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

Как вывести на странице только этот блок?

Изначально хотел использовать Simple HTML DOM Parser - но он не подходит, так как HTML файлы иногда приходят нестандартные, и он выдает ошибку `Call to a member function find() on a non-object`

Comment: `domDocument` и Xpath `//TBODY[@class="content"]`

Comment: @splash58 можно пожалуйста пример?

Comment: а проверить нельзя что ли перед вызовом `find()` что вызываете не на `null`  значении?

Comment: обычными строковыми функциями найдите этот искомый `<tbody>` и выкиньте все лишнее. самый быстрый способ будет.

Comment: @teran, а если таких `<tbody>` несколько?

Comment: @entithat пока что такого в задаче не было описано.

Comment: @Денис возьмите за основу код оттуда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769349/Регулярное-выражение-для-первого-родительского-элемента/769439#769439

Answer (score 0):

С помощью regular expression взять все, что `<tbody> ... </tbody>`

```
preg_match('/(<tbody.+?<\/tbody>)/mis', $find, $m)
var_dump($m);
```

https://regex101.com/r/SqgbqP/1

Замечание: такое сработает нормально только если в вашем `'./file.html'` только одна таблица. Иначе можно попробывать использовать `preg_match_all`